# Appending data from form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

no im i dont want php for now.
so heres my task... id like to get data from FORM then use that data for creating a new element using eventHandler .. also i want to keep the part where i use the event handler. the prob is that the appended data doesnt stay for long in d page. pls halp

```js
document.getElementById("fom").addEventListener("submit", performTask);

function performTask() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input = input.value;
  // console.log(input);
  // alert(input);

  var newList = document.createElement('li');
  newList.appendChild(input);
  var element = document.getElementById('orList');
  var child = document.getElementById('last');
  element.insertAfter(newList, child);

  //e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

```html
<form id="fom"> <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter list name" id="input" autofocus required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Append">
</form>

<ol id="orList">
  <li>List</li>
  <li>Another list</li>
  <li id="last">Some list</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: why you commented out `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: no reason at all :) still d code doesnt work

Comment: I suggest you look in the developer console to see the error that is being thrown by your `performTask` method, and which is preventing `e.preventDefault` from being called

Comment: @skymage101k Check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

First, what you were doing wrong:

1. The function `performTask` need to receive the `event` parameter
2. `evt.preventDefault()` Cancels the event if it is cancelable,
   without stopping further propagation of the event. (in your case
   submit event)
3. insertAfter is a Jquery function not javascript
4. I simplify the code by using insertAdjacentHTML javascript
   function. More info on this link:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
5. `newList.appendChild(input);` this line was wrong, because you cannot append a string.

Here your answer to your question:

```js
document.getElementById("fom").addEventListener("submit", performTask);

function performTask(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); 
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input = input.value;

  var d1 = document.getElementById('last');
  d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>'+input+'</li>');
 document.getElementById('input').value = '';
}
```

```html
<form id="fom" method="post"> <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter list name" id="input" autofocus required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Append">
</form>

<ol id="orList">
  <li>List</li>
  <li>Another list</li>
  <li id="last">Some list</li>
</ol>
```